# Truncate filename after a multiple of a special character in windows batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I want to remove the part of a filename after the third "_" from thousand of files. The structure after the third "_" varies and contains "_" in some cases. The length of the first part varies so I can't just remove the first 15 characters. The result should be unique.

The filenames look like this:

```
00_TEXT_=Text00._AA1234L_AA1_1.pdf
00_TEX_=Text00._AA1234L_AA1_2.pdf
00_TEXT_=TextText00._DD2023A.pdf
00_TEXT_=Text00._AA2345L_BB1_1.pdf
00_TEXT_=Text00._AA2345L_BB1_2.pdf
```

The result should look like this:

```
AA1234L_AA1_1.pdf
AA1234L_AA1_2.pdf
DD2023A.pdf
AA2345L_BB1_1.pdf
AA2345L_BB1_2.pdf
```

Any idea why this is not working:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set deletestring=*_*_*_
for /f "delims==" %%F in ('dir /b ^| find "%deletestring%"') do (
set oldfilename=%%F
set newfilename=!oldfilename:%deletestring%=!
Ren "!oldfilename!" "!newfilename!"
)
```

Comment: I replaced the % with %% but it didn't work - console showed:

     !filename!
     !filename!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working with this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set deletestring=*_*_*_*

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,* delims=_" %%F in ('dir /b "%deletestring%"') do (
    Ren "%%F_%%G_%%H_%%I" "%%I"
)

endlocal
```

Note that `enabledelayedexpansion` isn't really needed in the above.

Alternately, you could do this as a single line (no batch file needed):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,* delims=_" %F in ('dir /b "*_*_*_*"') do Ren "%F_%G_%H_%I" "%I"
```

The idea is to simply split the matching filenames apart by underscores and then reconstruct the names during the rename process (`%%F_%%G_%%H_%%I` gives the original file name when going through the loop). Then rename the file to everything after the 3rd underscore, which is the `%%I` value.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! Consecutive underscores are not an issue, as underscores are levels in the file system (till the 3rd underscore) so there has to be a folder name.
i thank you both and also eryksun.

Answer (score 2):

Your FINDSTR search is wrong - a string of any characters (wildcard) is `.*`, not `*`.

Variable find/replace does not support wildcards, except for the `!var:*search=!` syntax that replaces everthing up until the first occurrence of "search".

There is no need for FINDSTR, all you need is DIR with normal wildcard masking.

You can use FOR /F to parse the name into tokens. I use two loops - the first to get the entire name, and the second to parse out the portion after the 3rd `_`.

The following should work:

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d *_*_*_*'
) do for /f "tokens=3* delims=_" %%B in ("%%A") do ren "%%A" "%%C"
```

Or you could use my [jren.bat utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3) that renames files using regular expression replacement. It is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jren "^(.*?_){3}" ""
```

Use CALL JREN if you put the command within another batch script.

Comment: @eryksun - I fixed the delims oversight, thanks. A simple FOR should not be used because it could result in the same file being renamed multiple times. FOR /F buffers the entire result before it begins iterating, so it is guaranteed to only rename a file once. I add the `/a-d` option to ignore directory names.